# How to override magento_sale module phtml file?

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, phtml

I am unable to override this file in adminhtml of magento_sale module here is the path

```
vendor\magento\module-sales\view\adminhtml\templates\order\create\totals\shipping.phtml
```

The issue is that file is not rendering from layout and also can't find its block so how can i override this file any solutions

Answer (score 0):

**`Method 1`**

You can create your custom **module** and place this file in

**`app/code/Namespace/Modulename/view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_view.xml`**

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="shipping_info">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module::order/create/totals/shipping.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

and then create the template phtml file and place your code there.

**`app/code/Namespace/Modulename/view/adminhtml/templates/order/create/totals/shipping.phtml`**

**`Method 2`**

Another easy method is by placing the file in

```
app/design/adminhtml/Vendor/ThemeName/Magento_Sale/templates/order/create/totals/shipping.phtml
```

Please **`NOTE`** this :- You change any methods but run below commands

```
remove var/cache folder
remove var/view_preprocessed folder
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento c:c
php bin/magenot c:f
```

**`THANKS.`**

Comment: where to put that xml?file name or file layout name?

Comment: put xml file this path : -app/code/Namespace/Modulename/view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_view.xml